# Storing Different user types

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a system where there are various types of users. I am storing different information for each user. I am wondering whether I should store all users in one table or different tables because if I store in the same table, for some users, certain fields will be null.What is the best practise when it comes to this. My Database is MySql

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide more specific details?

Comment: The users types are parents and and children. The children information includes parent or guardian and other details like school or emergency contact..which in not there for the parent data

Answer (score 2):

For your example you should be ok with two tables:

- users_information(*id*,name,....)
- children_information(*id*, school, parent, etc)

where the id of a child refers to the id of a user.

This is a rather common way to implement the "is a" relation betwen *user* and *child* datatypes, in an object-oriented approach.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this approach

Answer (score 1):

For Register/Login as far as I'm concerned you'll have to store them in the same table. For other options like, the info they fill out on their profile, their profile picture, etc. I'd make another table for that. You could ask for details like, Are you a parent? If so, have that entered in the database. Maybe you could make it similar to Facebook, with the 'Sibling/Mother/Father' thing.

Answer (score 1):

The  best practice is different table. Remember you are using [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) . From wikipedia

> A relation is defined as a set of tuples that have the same
>   attributes. A tuple usually represents an object and information about
>   that object. Objects are typically physical objects or concepts. A
>   relation is usually described as a table, which is organized into rows
>   and columns. All the data referenced by an attribute are in the same
>   domain and conform to the same constraints.

So Your schema should always [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) way.